# Restart node js server with bash/shell script

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, shell

How can I restart my node js express server with a bash script? I tried it like this but this doesnt work:

```
while true; do 
    node server.js
done
```

What are the right commands to do that?

Comment: Wouldn't you need to check if it's down first?! In any case, there are existing tools to do this--might want to go down that path first.

Comment: The script would stop at the part where the programm is startet and only if the programm crashes it will continue the script. Thats how it should work.

Comment: Right, and I'm saying you don't do that, so you should. But you also don't want it in a tight loop. Which is why I'd point you in the direction of a myriad of options. Searching leads you to pages like this: https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/pm.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restart a node.js server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302959/how-to-restart-a-node-js-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's highly recommended to use a process manager such as [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io). You can install it using `npm install -g pm2`.
You can start your app by running `pm2 start app.js`.
It has more features you can use here [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io).

Comment: That looks great. So is there still a need to run a "screen" for the server?

Comment: @ToasterLoaster no there is no need such things as `screen`. your app will run forever.